# "Answer to the phone" and "Answer the phone"

Tags: prepositions, verbs, prepositional-phrases, to-infinitive, objects

If we want to use the verb *answer*, should we say: "answer to the phone" or "answer the phone"? How about other cases like answering (to) other things like someones question, query etc.

Comment: "Answer the phone". Or maybe "pick up the phone"?

Comment: Please see here for the definition of "[answer to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/answer+to)." Meanwhile, in the phrase, "the answer to someone's question," "answer" is a noun, not a verb, so the "to" acts in yet another capacity.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Prezackerly so. See my answer below! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *answer* is normally used either without any Complements, or with a Direct Object:

- "Yes", she answered. (no Complement)
- Answer the question. (with Direct Object, *the question*)
- I answered him. (with Direct Object *him*)
- Answer the phone. (with Direct Object *phone*)

When *answer* means to respond as in the sentences above, it does not take preposition phrases as Complements:

- *Answer to the question. (ungrammatical)
- *I answered to him. (ungrammatical when used with this meaning).
- *Answer to the phone. (ungrammatical)

Nouns cannot take Objects. For this reason when we use the *noun* "answer", we put the thing being answered in a preposition phrase with *to*:

- The answer to the question ...
- My answer to him ...

---

<sup>**Note**</sup>

<sup>There is another meaning of the verb *answer*, ***to take orders from, obey, and explain your actions to someone:*** [(definition from Cambridge Dictionaries)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/answer-to-sb). When used with this meaning the verb *answer* takes a *to*-preposition phrase as a Complement:</sup>

> <sup>The Vice-Principal answers directly to the Principal.</sup>

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but mind if I edit your post to say, "When *answer* means to respond as in the sentences above, it does not take preposition phrases as Complements because it is **a noun**:" I just want to make it more clear for readers that the reason is because it is a noun.

Comment: And as an aside, you've spelled "Complements" wrong :D.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Yes, edit away. Thanks! (I'm working now so can't loiter on ELL!!!) [But you mean *because it is a ***verb***, right?]

Comment: Heh, yes, exactly! So I didn't even edit it; only corrected the spelling :D.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about this case: a search engines answers to the user's query. or should it be: a search engine answers user's query.

Comment: @lonesome "a search engine answers **A** user's query" :-)